# apps script: increase variable with each execution

Tags: variables, google-apps-script, global-variables, average

Hi i have a list of values each value representing the output of a shift of packaging. I want to calculate the average output of 8 weeks. So each time a shift passes the average output changes. My idea is to trigger a function after each shift, which calculates the output. Now theres my problem, how do i get a varible (the one representing the row of the first value) to increase after each trigger of the function? What i tried is to declare the variable before the function and increase the variable of 1 inside the function. Buf ofc the starting value doesnt change this way.. Probably there is an easy way for this i just dont know yet (programming newbie here :)).

```
let i = 7;
let j = 126;

function schnitt() {
 

var summe = 0;
var counter = 0;
i++;
j++;

while(i <= j){
  var aktuell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(i,6,1,1).getValue();
  if(aktuell != ""){
    summe = summe + aktuell;
    counter++;
    i++;
  }
    else{
      i++
    }
}
  var durchschnitt  = summe / counter;
  var ausgabe = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(8,7,1,1).setValue(durchschnitt);
  
}
```

Comment: Can you paste a code, so that people here can know how to fix your issue? Also have you tried to put your function in a loop?

Comment: Hi provided the code, thx for the reminder. No i did not try that, but to be honest i dont know how one would do that :D

Comment: Check the following two pages of documentation: 
https://spreadsheet.dev/arrays-apps-script 
https://spreadsheet.dev/loops-apps-script

Comment: @raffi how do these help? I dont understand..

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around. I just put var i and j into cells and do it like this:

```
function schnitt() {
 
var i = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(3,14,1,1).getValue();
var j = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(4,14,1,1).getValue();
var summe = 0;
var counter = 0;


while(i <= j){
  var aktuell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(i,6,1,1).getValue();
  if(aktuell != ""){
    summe = summe + aktuell;
    counter++;
    i++;
  }
    else{
      i++
    }
}
  var durchschnitt  = summe / counter;
  var ausgabe = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(8,7,1,1).setValue(durchschnitt);

  i = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(3,14,1,1).getValue();
  i++;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(3,14,1,1).setValue(i);
  
  j = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(4,14,1,1).getValue();
  j++;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auswertung").getRange(4,14,1,1).setValue(j);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need script at all? It looks like all you need is just a couple of classic Excel formulas to sum and to get average from a given range. If you need a script by some reason, let me know. This your script can be improved.

Comment: Yes i do need the script, bacause i need it to be newly calculated after each shift. Also usually thers is no night shift and those should not be included then. So how would you improve this, im fairly new in programming and happy for any advice :)